# Java - parse CSV into Hashmap and Arraylist based on columns

Tags: java, parsing, csv, arraylist, hashmap

I would like to ask for help with this task: I have CSV for example like this:

```
column1$column2$column3
123$xyz$321
456$zyx$654
```

And I would like to parse it by Java, so I would have a Hashmap of Array lists for every column.
For example:

```
["column1",[123,456]]
["column2",[xyz,zyx]]
["column3",[321,654]]
```

Thanks everyone.

Someone already gave me advice how to solve this task by array lists of array lists, but I would like to use the Hashmap, so I could have the index of the column. How could I edit this code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> columns = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testing.cvs"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] fields = sCurrentLine.split("\\$");
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                if (columns.size()<=i){
                    columns.add(new ArrayList<String>());
                }
                columns.get(i).add(fields[i]);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank everyone

Answer (score 0):

Lets pass you some code while I'm at it....

In this solution I use two `Maps` one for the `column name` - `values` and one for the `index` - `column name`

On first row, I fill index the maps, then I start filling them...

```
Map<String, List<String>> mappedCols = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
Map<Integer, String> indexCols = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    String sCurrentLine;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testing.cvs"));
    boolean firstLine = true;
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] fields = sCurrentLine.split("\\$");
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if (firstLine) {
                indexCols.put(i, fields[i]);
                mappedCols.put(fields[i], new ArrayList<String>());
            } else {
                String colName = indexCols.get(i);
                if (colName == null) {
                    break;
                }
                mappedCols.get(colName).add(fields[i]);
            }
        }
        firstLine = false;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null)
            br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The result that you are after is in the `mappedCols`

Answer (score 0):

Not tested - but should be pretty close -

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> columnsMap = new HashMap<>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testing.cvs"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] fields = sCurrentLine.split("\\$");

                for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                    String columnKey = "column" + (i + 1);
                    List<String> columnValuesList = columnsMap.get(columnKey);
                    if (columnValuesList == null) {
                        columnValuesList = new ArrayList<>();
                    }

                    columnValuesList.add(fields[i]);
                    columnsMap.put(columnKey, columnValuesList);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solutions makes use of columns HashMap> that takes a String as key (column name) and ArrayList as value. I have tested it with n number of columns and rows and work just fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //hashmap with column as key and values as arraylist
    Map<String, List<String>> columns = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    //column names
    List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.csv"));

        //header flag
        boolean header = true; 

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] fields = sCurrentLine.split("\\$");

            for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {   
                if(header) {
                    //array list as null, since we don't have values yet
                    columns.put(fields[i], null); 

                    //also seperately store the column names to be used to as key to get the list
                    columnNames.add(fields[i]);

                    //reached end of the header line, set header to false 
                    if(i == (fields.length-1))
                        header = false;
                } else {
                    //retrieve the list using the column names
                    List<String> tempList = columns.get(columnNames.get(i)); 

                    if(tempList != null) {
                        //if not null then already element there
                        tempList.add(fields[i]); 
                    } else {
                        //if null then initialize the list
                        tempList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                        tempList.add(fields[i]);
                    }
                    //add modified list back to the map
                    columns.put(columnNames.get(i), tempList); 
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("columns: " + columns.toString());
    //columns: {column1=[123, 456], column3=[321, 654], column2=[xyz, zyx]}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial)' `ColumnProcessor` to do this for you reliably:

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
parserSettings.getFormat().setDelimiter('$');
parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

// To get the values of all columns, use a column processor
ColumnProcessor rowProcessor = new ColumnProcessor();
parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

//This will kick in our column processor
parser.parse(new FileReader("testing.cvs"));

//Finally, we can get the column values:
Map<String, List<String>> columnValues = rowProcessor.getColumnValuesAsMapOfNames();
```

Clean, faster and easiers than doing it by hand. This will handle situations such as rows with different number of columns and add `null` to the list instead of throwing exceptions at you.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).