# How to map 3 Lists, where the values of the first are the keys and the values on the rest are the values of the map?

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

Suppose this list example `[[a,b,c],[1, ,3],[12,34, ]]` is list of lists.
Trying to  convert this into map where in map would be like this.

```
a = 1, 12
b = null, 34
c = 3, null
```

Please note i have already created above list of list from string of below type

```
a:b:c|1::3|12:34:|
```

Approach here was to convert this string first to list of lists and then make the first list elements as keys and rest other as values to this keys.

Comment: Please share your efforts (edit your post)

Comment: So, what you can't achieve, where did you stuck. If you are looking for some approach with this: go through your list in the loop and fill the map with first element of each embedded list as a key and the rest of embedded list as a value.

Comment: Why are you converting to list first? Also it is a direct logic and can be done by just trying out.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33744327/1553851

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- first you need to iterate over the element of the first list(a b c)
- then, for each you need to iterate over the others lists (from index 1)
- and get back their value in same order

---

Complete code for direct use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")));
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", null, "3")));
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("12", "34", null)));

    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.get(0).size(); i++) {
        List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 1; j < list.get(0).size(); j++) {
            value.add(list.get(j).get(i));
        }
        map.put(list.get(0).get(i), value);
    }       

    System.out.println(map.toString()); // {a=[1, 12], b=[null, 34], c=[3, null]}
}
```

---

Tips

`List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));` allows you to add (later) other elements to the list

`List<String> list list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");` does not allow to add other element later

---

[`Code Demo`](https://ideone.com/t3xWW6)

Comment: You can use `Arrays.asList` to build the outer list too, and there is no need to convert lists to `ArrayList`: `List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList( Arrays.asList("a","b","c"), Arrays.asList("1",null,"3"), Arrays.asList("12","34",null) );`